# Creating a Binary Expression Tree given prefix notation in java

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

How should we construct the binary tree of the following "prefix" order expression?

( - * / 8 + 5 1 4 + 3 - 5 / 18 6 )
4

**Pseudocode is like this:**

```
public ExpressionRootNode MakeBinaryTree(expr):
    element = next element in expr
    if element is a number:
        return a leaf node of that number
    else: // element is an operator
        left = MakeBinaryTree(expr)
        right = MakeBinaryTree(expr)
        return a binary tree with subtrees left and right and with operator element
        //^aka return root
```

However, I dont quite understand how to recursively call the function to create said tree.
I have tried looking at *how to* [Create a binary tree from an algebraic expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866587/create-a-binary-tree-from-an-algebraic-expression), but can't figure out how to backtrack up to the other node.

Project files : http://pastebin.com/BJiPtDM5, its a mess.

Comment: How about **returning** it? Not all methods must be `void` you know.

Comment: Edited the pseudocode to change from void -> ExpressionRootNode

Comment: Good! You have the operation, the left subtree and the right subtree. What exactly is your problem to create the corresponding Tree instance?

Comment: Doesn't the function need to call itself WITH its parent root? How will it know who's left and whose right to be called? Would this.left and this.right work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More pseudocode:

```
abstract class Tree { .... }
class Leave extends Tree { int number; ... }
class Expr  extends Tree { Tree left, right; String operation;  .... }

public Tree makeBinaryTree(expr):
   element = next element in expr
   if element is a number:
      return new Leave(element)
   else: // element is an operator
      left = makeBinaryTree(expr)
      right = makeBinaryTree(expr)
   return new Expr(left, right, element)
```

The constructors of Leave/Expr are expected to just  set the fields from their arguments.

What is left to be done is some error handling, though. Ohh, and make sure that "next element in expr" also removes the part already dealt with.

Given a correct input, it will work like this:

- if the input is just a number, it will return a Leave with that number
- if the input is of the form OP L R, it will remember OP, make the left subtree from L and the right subtree from R and return that as expression.
- no other inputs are possible/valid

Example:

```
* + 5 1 7
```

will result in:

```
Expr(Expr(Leave(5), Leave(1), "+"), Leave(7), "*")
```

Note that those prefix expressions cannot see if "-" is supposed to be unary negation or binary subtraction. Hence you can't use the same operator character for that.

Comment: This doesnt account for setting the root node. It will create a null root with left and right childs. Root will be blank.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/izcuMTuZ this is what I got with your code. I'm trying to create a ExpressionTree. Do I just call makeBinaryTree in ExpressionTree's constructor, and then just cast (ExpressionTree) to the result of makeBinaryTree?

Comment: I managed to get it I think. All I need to do is figure out how to turn this tree of Expr's into one whole ExpressionTree.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s1RxYN7x ... Also weird that I cant call root.data http://i.imgur.com/g62a064.png

Comment: @jakeinmn Yes, it creates a tree, and that's it. If you need to set some variable (root node?), you can do that in a method that calls this. I am not sure what you mean with ExpressionTree? Please show your definition of it. The code is thought to get adapted to your data structure.

Answer (score -2):

See the last two answers here.

[parsing math expression in c/c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703082/parsing-math-expression-in-c-c)

I think they are quite useful.

You need a formal grammar and then a recursive descent parser.
Not sure if you're fully familiar with these two concepts.
If not, you should read some more about them.

Comment: Sorry, he doesn't need a recursive descent parser for this.

Comment: OK... Could be. Just a stack maybe? :)

Comment: His pseudo code is already good. He's just a bit confused about parameter passing.