# Javacc conflicting productions

Tags: javacc

I have two inputs

1. `a - b`
2. `a += b`

And I have a production with a choice

```
void AssignmentExpression() : {}
{
  LOOKAHEAD(3) ConditionalExpression()
| LOOKAHEAD(3) UnaryExpression() AssignmentOperator() AssignmentExpression()
}
```

With this production input (1) works, but input (2) does not work.

If I swap the choice in the production so that it becomes

```
void AssignmentExpression() : {}
{
  LOOKAHEAD(3) UnaryExpression() AssignmentOperator() AssignmentExpression()
| LOOKAHEAD(3) ConditionalExpression()
}
```

Then input (2) works, but input (1) does not work.

How do I fix this? Increasing the LOOKAHEAD parameter does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Expression Parsing by Recursive Descent](https://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/Misc/exp_parsing.htm). Follow the "classic solution".

Since you are using JJTree, the answer to the question [Make a calculator's grammar that make a binary tree with javacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846777/make-a-calculators-grammar-that-make-a-binary-tree-with-javacc) will be helpful.

Comment: Hello, I cannot change the grammar. Please take another look.

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
void AssignmentExpression() : {}
{
  LOOKAHEAD(UnaryExpression() AssignmentOperator() )
  UnaryExpression() AssignmentOperator() AssignmentExpression()
| ConditionalExpression()
}
```

Without seeing more of the grammar it is hard to know whether this will work.  Since the use of the lookahead specification will suppress any warnings from JavaCC --JavaCC "assumes" you know what you are doing-- you have to do the analysis yourself.

My other answer is better.